# Installing OpenCV3 for Python 3.4 on Windows10

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, pip, installation

I have troubles to install `OpenCV3` for `Python3.4` in `Widnows 10`.

I have already installed numpy which seems the first thing to do..

```
C:\Users\Mourad\Desktop>py -m pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\mourad\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

Now what I am trying to do is:

```
C:\Users\Mourad\Desktop>py -m pip install cv2
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Collecting cv2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2
```

EDIT :

This is finnaly the solution that worked for me, after days of trying. You just follow the stpes of this tutorial:

[install opencv 3 with python 3 on windows](https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

In StackOverflow opencv documentation, this topic was explained with a step by step guide.  Since SO Documentation is retired, there were two links that helped commentators:

- [OpenCV 3 Python Tutorial for Windows Setup](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html)
- [Install OpenCV 3 with Python 3 on Windows](https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/)

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio and don't want to use it, is there any other way I can directly install it without it ?? I use PyCharm for developpement or Canopy I don't want to install a third IDE.

Comment: In this link both method are explained using visual studio or cmake 
  http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Comment: I tried to do exactly the same steps but it dosn't work when I use cmake and choose the build and source folders  !

Comment: I finally found the solution and the right tutrial on how to do it !

https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

What I did was first installed numpy then installed `opencv-python` not `cv2` using pip.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is finnaly the solution that worked for me, after days of trying. You just follow the stpes of this tutorial:

[install opencv 3 with python 3 on windows](https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/)